# Android Seekbar snap to value

Tags: android, intellij-idea, seekbar

I created an android application which contains 3 seekbars. I want it to snap to the middle value when u scroll. So if the max of the seekbar is 100 it will snap to 50 when it's close to this value.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**: I managed to create something that works:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            if (progress > 90 && progress < 110 ) {
                                                sk.setProgress(100);
                                                progress = 100;
                                            }
```

The seekbar has a max of 200

Comment: Consider using a RatingBar, instead

Comment: If that works, consider posting it as an answer